# Show Pages in Categories

Tags: categories

I created category function by adding this code to functions.php:

```
function page_category() {  
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'page');  
}
 // Add to the admin_init hook of your theme functions.php file 
add_action( 'init', 'page_category' );
```

But the thing is that when I go to a category page, the page does not show the pages that are in the category. I read it is because categories are meant to show only posts.

Is there any way show pages in categories, without using a plugin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you try:

```
function my_custom_show_pages_in_category( $query ){
     if( $query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ){
           $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'page' ) ) ;
     }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_custom_show_pages_in_category' );
```

See more: [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)